# Python3.5.2 Reversed method string

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> x = "hello world"
>>> y = reversed(x)
>>> z = ''.join(y)
>>> z
'dlrow olleh'
>>> y
<reversed object at 0x7f2871248b38>
>>> ''.join(y)
''
>>> x
'hello world'
>>> ''.join(y)
''
>>> z = ''.join(y)
>>> z
''
```

Why I am getting the value of z next time as blank string after doing join operation in reversed function

Comment: Please read [the](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed) [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because reversed returns an iterator, when you apply an operation on it, it "consumes" the element. If you want to store the result of reversed in a variable, join is a good way to do it.

```
from collections.abc import Iterator

print(isinstance(reversed("hello world"), Iterator)) # True

it = reversed("hello world")
for x in it:
    print(x) # Prints the letters

for x in it:
    print(x) # Do not print them, there are already "consumed"
```

Comment: Thanks.I had completely forgotten about  the return object of reversed function, which is an iterator

Comment: Yes Boss!(bow and salute) You absolutely  and unambiguously answered my question :)